# IntentService does not start

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, intentservice

My `IntentService` looks like this:

```
public class MusicService extends IntentService{

    final static String NAME = "MusicService";

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public MusicService(String name) {
        super(NAME);
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public MusicService() {
        super(NAME);
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Toast never comes up
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), NAME, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        PodcastrApplication.newInstance().getMediaPlayer().start();
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

I have a `MediaPlayer` that I keep in my `Application` to reduce object instantiations. The idea is that once the app goes out of focus, the media player will play. However, **the service is never fired.**

Here is how I am calling the service from the `onStop()` of my `Fragment`

```
showMediaPlayerNotification();
Intent music = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicService.class);
getActivity().startService(music);
```

I have it declared in the manifest also. There is no error in logcat, either.

What is going on?

**Update 1:**

> Once you call startService(), the IntentService does the work defined
>   in its onHandleIntent() method, and then stops itself.

Is it that the service is stopping itself because it is just one line of execution?
Should I move the media player to a thread?

**Update 2:**

```
<service
            android:name=".service.MusicService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: I even had a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065263/classical-intentservice-doesnt-starts?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've called `Toast.makeText()` in a background thread!, Any UI stuff must be done in UI thread.

Note that: `IntentService` uses a background thread but `Service` uses UI thread

You can try:

```
public class MusicService extends IntentService{

    Handler mHandler;
    final static String NAME = "MusicService";

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public MusicService(String name) {
        super(NAME);
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public MusicService() {
        super(NAME);
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable{

            @Override
            public void run(){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), NAME, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }            

        });
        // Toast never comes up

        PodcastrApplication.newInstance().getMediaPlayer().start();
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: So, how do I know if my service is actually starting? :)

Comment: @LittleChild a simple way could be putting `Log.d(...)` and then checking the console!